# Django model formsets - modifying form labels and defaults

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I'm building a formset like so:

```
InterestFormSet = modelformset_factory(Interest, \
    formset=BaseInterestFormSet, exclude=('userid',), extra=2)
```

And I want set default labels and values for elements of this form.

I know that in simple forms I can use the `fields` dict to change these things for specific fields of the form, but how is this done with a formset?

I tried extending the formset (as you can see) to see if I could access `self.fields` from within `__init__`, but no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should do what you want:

```
class InterestForm(ModelForm):
    pub_date = DateField(label='Publication date')

    class Meta:
        model = Interest
        exclude = ('userid',)


InterestFormSet = modelformset_factory(Interest, form=InterestForm, extra=2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Formsets don't have fields, they only have forms which have fields. So you have to deal directly with those forms.

Comment: Is it possible to get the forms that comprise a formset?